# Making a simple slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make a slider, one with multiple photos through which you can navigate with arrows?

I already have the images and the arrows in the page. Should I hide all the images and when an arrow is clicked hide the current image and display the next/prev?

I have the images in a list.

Comment: If you're a beginner, you should definitely not write your own slider. There are countless free versions which are just one Google search away from you.

Comment: You can see the functionality and demo on http://wowslider.com/jquery-content-slider-stream-fly-demo.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to review [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow. Also, whether your question is [**On-Topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for it. Make your own, it's the best way to learn how things work. Here's a guide to a simple show/hide box with arrows:

1. Hide all images with css.
2. Show only the image with class `current`.
3. Use jQuery on load function to add `current` class to the first element (you can also handle a preload or something here)
4. on arrow click assign current image to a variable like `var current = $('.imgClass.current')`, remove `current` class from all images (`$('.imgClass').removeClass('current')`), and add it to the `current.next()` or `.prev()`. If `next()` or `prev()` is undefined, add it to element number `0` or `$('.imgClass').length - 1` accordingly with (`$('.imgClass').eq(n).addClass('current')`).

Comment: Shouldn't I first remove the class current from all the images and THEN to add class current for the first image in the list?

Comment: Nope, that is the first time it is loaded, none of the images has the class "current" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
var t = document.getElementById("sd"),
    e = document.createElement("img"),
    n = ["2", "3", "4"],
    d = 0;
t.appendChild(e), setInterval(function() {
    e.setAttribute("src", n[d]), e.style.height = "200px", e.style.width = "470px", d++, d >= n.length && (d = 0)
}, 1800)
})();
```

this is simple pure js slider just make a div by id (sd) in any where in your html page for add your image src change the 
 n = ["2", "3", "4"], with your image path
like
 n = ["images/car.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.png"],
also u can add more image and u can change the width and height of image from 
e.style.height = "200px", e.style.width = "470px"

.........
now how can make slider 
we have multi image lets say its 5 and all image src (path) was on one array
now the slider show one image its the first one and for show the second
its change the src of image by second src on array and if it on the last array item (last image on array) its back to first item (image src ) and you can see the code above :)